# Sci Fi book about a girl falling from space onto a polluted Earth and is trying to repair a ship to get back

Tags: story-identification, books

It's been around 3 years since I read the book, but I remember vague details of a delicate girl falling from outer space onto a polluted Earth, where she tries to recuperate and get to know other people.

There also was something about her trying to repair a spaceship so she can get back into orbit; she also meets a boy if that helps...

Comment: "Earth" as in "Cradle of humanity" or as in "any sufficiently Earth-like planet" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This reminds me a lot of Becky Chamber's [A Closed and Common Orbit](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29475447-a-closed-and-common-orbit) from 2016.

I don't see any synopsis entries online that match with your description, but I also read this a couple of years ago and it ties in with my memory.

From memory:

- Pepper is imprisoned as a worker on a recycling planet
- She is genetically engineered to repair electronics as part of her work
- She escapes the facility and finds a broken space ship (and AI) that she manages to befriend, repair, and escape
- There's a boy involved later in the book

[image: Cover of "A Closed and Common Orbit". The title and author's name are all in lowercase. The cover shows a background of shooting stars against a night sky, with the silhouette of two people standing on uneven ground visible on the lower middle part of the cover.]